# How to solve frozen welcome screen on hp laptop?

Tags: windows

I don't know if this question is relevant or not, but i need a solution badly.

I am Having problem with starting up my laptop (HP ultrabook Folio 9470m, Windows 10)

While switching it on, its get frozen in welcome interface after providing passcode. A black screen appears after waiting for a while. And screen remains black after that. Sometimes mouse click doesn't work. I can't go into any advanced startup option or something. And I am sort of novice in term of using laptop. This problem appear out of blue.
Any solution?

Comment: Can you may try to boot into safe mode and check if the problems still exists? The next thing i would recommend is using Windows Recovery.